# A better way to handle async saving to backend server and cloud storage from React Native app

Tags: react-native, asynchronous, async-await

In my React Native 0.63.2 app, after user uploads images of artwork, the app will do 2 things:

```
1. save artwork record and image records on backend server
2. save the images into cloud storage
```

Those 2 things are related and have to be done successfully all together. Here is the code:

```
const clickSave = async () => {
    console.log("save art work");
    try {
        //save artwork to backend server
        let art_obj = {
            _device_id,
            name,
            description,
            tag: (tagSelected.map((it) => it.name)),
            note:'',
        }; 
        let img_array=[], oneImg;
        imgs.forEach(ele => {
            oneImg = {
                fileName:"f"+helper.genRandomstring(8)+"_"+ele.fileName,
                path: ele.path,
                width: ele.width,
                height: ele.height,
                size_kb:Math.ceil(ele.size/1024),
                image_data: ele.image_data,
            };
            img_array.push(oneImg);              
        });
        art_obj.img_array = [...img_array];
        art_obj = JSON.stringify(art_obj);
        //assemble images
        
        let url = `${GLOBAL.BASE_URL}/api/artworks/new`;
        await helper.getAPI(url, _result, "POST", art_obj);  //<<==#1. send artwork and image record to backend server

        //save image to cloud storage
        var storageAccessInfo =  await helper.getStorageAccessInfo(stateVal.storageAccessInfo);
        if (storageAccessInfo && storageAccessInfo !== "upToDate")   
            //update the context value            
            stateVal.updateStorageAccessInfo(storageAccessInfo);
            //
            let bucket_name = "oss-hz-1";  //<<<
            const configuration = {
                maxRetryCount: 3,  
                timeoutIntervalForRequest: 30,
                timeoutIntervalForResource: 24 * 60 * 60
            };
                
            const STSConfig = {
                AccessKeyId:accessInfo.accessKeyId,
                SecretKeyId:accessInfo.accessKeySecret,
                SecurityToken:accessInfo.securityToken
            }
            const endPoint = 'oss-cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com';  //<<<
            const last_5_cell_number = _myself.cell.substring(myself.cell.length - 5);
            let filePath, objkey;
            img_array.forEach(item => {
                console.log("init sts");
                AliyunOSS.initWithSecurityToken(STSConfig.SecurityToken,STSConfig.AccessKeyId,STSConfig.SecretKeyId,endPoint,configuration)
                //console.log("before upload", AliyunOSS);
                objkey = `${last_5_cell_number}/${item.fileName}`;  //virtual subdir and file name
                filePath = item.path;
                AliyunOSS.asyncUpload(bucket_name, objkey, filePath).then( (res) => { //<<==#2 send images to cloud storage with callback. But no action required after success.
                    console.log("Success : ", res) //<<==not really necessary to have console output
                }).catch((error)=>{
                    console.log(error)  
                })
            })


    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
        return false;
    };
};
```

The concern with the code above is that those 2 async calls may take long time to finish while user may be waiting for too long. After clicking saving button, user may just want to move to next page on user interface and leaves those everything behind. Is there a way to do so? is removing `await` (#1) and `callback` (#2) able to do that?

Comment: You may want to do that in redux action so it handled in background. Just out of curiosity why doesn't your backend do the cloud task?

Comment: `SaachiTech`, I am not using redux in the app. Is there other way to do without redux? About image cloud storage, since the image file is on the device which runs the app, I thought it would be more efficient for the app to handle the saving to cloud storage. If backend server handles the saving of images, then the images have to be uploaded to backend server first before the server can save it to cloud. It would be a lot load and traffic in and out of backend server.

Comment: There could be many ways to handle upload in background. You can create a global function or a class with upload function. Redux is good because it can update state so the app can show success message to user on any screen.

Comment: The app uses context for keeping and sharing states. Since the image uploading is a critical task and I am not sure if it is good to be handled as a complete backgroud task.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do both tasks in the background, then you can't use await. I see that you are using await on sending the images to the backend, so remove that and use `.then().catch();` you don't need to remove the callback on #2.

If you need to make sure #1 finishes before doing #2, then you will need to move the code for #2 intp #1's promise resolving code (inside the .then()).

Now, for catching error. You will need some sort of error handling that alerts the user that an error had occurred and the user should trigger another upload. One thing you can do is a red banner. I'm sure there are packages out there that can do that for you.

Comment: Image uploading is a critical task and I am not sure if it is good to run completely as background task.

Comment: that's why i suggested to create an error handling just in case there's an error. The only  difference between running the task in the background vs the foreground is that the user needs to wait for it to finish before doing anything else on the UI.

Comment: `await` and promises are different syntax for same thing